# destroy $_SESSION after clicking 'Cancel' button

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to destroy $_SESSION['userList'] after cliking 'Cancel' button. However, the $_SESSION['userList'] is destroied when page load.

Below is my code:

```
<a href='#' class="btn" onClick="resetForm()"><span>Cancel</span></a>

<script type="text/javascript">

                function resetForm() {
                    <?php

                        unset($_SESSION['userList']);

                    ?>

                }
            </script>
```

Really appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAVASCRIPT

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "phppage.php",
    data: "action=unsetsession",
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
        if(msg == "success"){
            //cleared session
        }else{
            //failed
        }
    },
    error: function(msg){
        alert('Error: cannot load page.');
    }
});
```

PHP

```
if($_POST['action'] == "unsetsession"){
    unset($_SESSION['userList']);
    echo "success";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot execute PHP (server-side) in your javascript (client-side). You need to issue an HTTP request to invoke PHP. You can do that using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

You can not execute php code in the client side like you try in your example. If you want to to destroy session withou reload then you must use ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

You better use jquery for this

```
<a href='#' class="btn" onClick="resetForm()"><span>Cancel</span></a>

<script>
function resetForm()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "cancel.php",
        data:,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And create a new `cancel.php` which will be like this -

```
<?php
unset($_SESSION['userList']);
?>
```

Comment: @MakuraYami why don't you take out some time and CAREFULLY compare those two posts and then arrive at any conclusion.

Comment: You mean putting in in a function and adding cache is such a big difrence? good luck with it mate.

Comment: @MakuraYami Sorry to ask, but are you trying to say that you actually invented this solution and no two people can program in a same way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call PHP from JS like this. You'll need to do a call back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use submit button for Cancel (You can use CSS to make it look the away you want)
//HTML

```
<form method="post" >
<input type="button" value="Cancel" name="cancel" id="cancel" />
</form>
```

//PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['cancel'))
{
  unset($_SESSION['userList']);
}
```